# How to connect to remote MariaDB server

Tags: database, intellij-idea, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a server running on Raspberry Pi (MariaDB) on my network.
I also have this database connected in IntelliJ Idea Database Tool through SSH.

How can I connect to this Database through a code running on my local machine?